# XPages: DropDown selection of documents

Tags: xpages

I have a VERY general question and am not 100% sure if I am just being lazy or what, I just cannot seem to get a handle on where to start :o)

I am new to XPages programming and have created an application that works well enough, the problem is that I would like to UI to be totally different to what I have. I find that my implementation is much too "Notes like" and not "Web like" enough. OK, enough whining - I have a document that contains a county, a province, a city and some text to that particular city. Currently I display a view (XPage) listing all documents by county / province / city. The user then selects the city document which is then opened to display the text. Works well enough. As you can see very "Notes like". What I would like is this: The user sees 3 drop down fields (two of which cannot be selected), s/he then selects the country from the drop down. The province field now becomes active only displaying the provinces for that Country. S/he selects the province and all the cities are now is the next drop down - once you select the city the text is displayed below the city name. Quite simple I thought - now matter what I do I cannot get this to work :o(

Any pointers (maybe an example app somewhere?).

Thanks in advance

Greetings
Ursus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do is get a copy of the Mastering XPages book and read through that. Then you should look at how rendering and partial refreshes will help you do what you want.

You are going to want to set the rendering to false until you enter some value in the previous field. Then, in the event, you determine if the value is valid and set a flag (could be a simple viewScope) and do a partial refresh of the next field. In that field's properties, you check the viewScope flag that you just set in the previous field and if it is correct, you reset the rendering to true to show the field.

Comment: Funnily enough I do have the book - as a relatively new XPages programmer I find the book a little overwhelming. I also have the XPages Extension Library book - I'll look into them both this weekend. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It can be overwhelming at first but it will eventually make sense. Good luck and if you have more questions (you will) post them here.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented exactly that kind of feature on the homepage of ilsschools.co.uk using client side onchange event:

```
var com2 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:comboBox2}");
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:comboBox2}",
    { onComplete : com2.selectedIndex = 0 });
```

We get the element we want to refresh (i.e. comboBox2 and we do this for comboxBox3, 4 etc as well). Then we use partialRefreshGet to refresh the choices in comboBox2, this can be repeated for 3, 4 and other comboBoxes as well. You can compute the disabled property of a comboBox to disable it. You can compute the selections for a comboBox using SSJS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll look into it on the weekend :o)